# How do I get rid of multiple columns with the same name in R?

Tags: r, join, merge, duplicates, multiple-columns

I'm gathering SAT scores by school districts in Texas and their amount of education spending. The data for SAT scores come in csv files that are split by year. I want to consolidate the scores into my dataframe that has the amount of education spending without creating multiple columns for Total, Math score, Reading score, etc.

I've tried the different types of join functions, `semi_join`, `full_join`, `left_join`, etc. but none of these seems to address the issue I am having.

```
temp1<-left_join(temp, sat17, by= c("District","year"))%>% 

left_join(., sat16, by=c("District","year"))%>%

left_join(., sat15, by=c("District","year"))%>%

left_join(., sat14, by=c("District","year"))%>%

left_join(., sat13, by=c("District","year"))%>%

left_join(., sat12, by=c("District","year"))%>%

left_join(., sat11, by=c("District","year"))
```

The output gives me columns Math.x, Math.y, Total.x, Total.y, and so on for each joined dataframe. Also, sat17 includes a column called ERW, instead of Reading because the test changed that year. I want to keep ERW separate, and the rest of the Reading, Math, and Total scores to line up under one of each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

`dplyr` is automatically going to rename any columns that you don't join by **and** have a matching column name in the joined data set.

In your case, since you only want to join `by=c("District", "year")`, any other columns that have the same name will get renamed.

The starting data set columns getting `.x` appended to the end of their name, while the columns being left joined get `.y` appended to the end of their name.

#### Solution

If you want to have Math, Reading, and Total all in the same column, then you need to stack the data sets in top of each other with `dplyr::bind_rows()`

```
combined_sat <- dplyr::bind_rows(sat17, sat16, sat15, sat14, sat13, sat12,  sat11)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want to do is to bind them together... that is to "add" them up one on the top of the other.

Try:

```
do.call(rbind, dfs) # dfs is the list of dataframes
```

or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
bind_rows(dfs, .id = NULL)
```

Comment: The do.call function sort of addresses the issue, but results in a stacked output that is different from what I need. The bind_rows function doesn't seem to address the issue, at least the way that I assume it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Or say you want to just bind them at the .csv level to begin with, just throw all your files into a subdirectory called "data". You can try something like this:

```
setwd("./data/")
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
binded_data <- tibble(filenames = list.files()) %>%
  mutate(yearly_sat = map(filenames, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest()
```

Comment: So I tried this:
setwd("C:/Users/wasd777/Desktop/project/")
library(purrr)
binded_data <- tibble(filenames = list.files("sat_2017.csv","sat_2016.csv","sat_2015.csv","sat_2014.csv","sat_2013.csv","sat_2012.csv","sat_2011.csv"))%>%
  mutate(yearly_sat = map(filenames, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest()

But I got an error: Error in list.files("sat_2017.csv", "sat_2016.csv", "sat_2015.csv", "sat_2014.csv",  : 
  invalid 'all.files' argument


What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function list.files() returns a vector that just contains the names of all files in the current directory. In this case, either throw all the desired files into a new folder and and change the directory or just run library(purrr) library(tidverse) binded_data <- tibble(filenames = c("sat_2017.csv","sat_2016.csv","sat_2015.csv","sat_2014.csv","sat_2013.csv","sat_2012.csv","sat_2011.csv"))%>% mutate(yearly_sat = map(filenames, read_csv)) %>% unnest()